# Actualizar registro en base de datos

Tags: android-sqlite

Tengo una duda, quisiera actualizar un registro de cinco de una base de datos en `SQLite` y que la lista resultante aparezca los cuatros registro no actualizados junto al nuevo registro.

Me estoy liando y no se si será necesario crear varios constructores. Creé la clase `Modelo` para llamarla a la hora de actualizar todos los registros pero cuando necesito sólo modificar uno de ellos,me surge la duda.

```
public class Modelo {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String age;
    private String phone;
    private byte[] image;

    public Modelo(int id, String name, String age, String phone, byte[] image) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.image = image;
    }
```

Espero me puedan aclarar algo

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y la duda cual es?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para eso tienes el método update()

Usas tu modelo

```
Modelo modeloBE = new Modelo();
modeloBE.id = "1";
modeloBE.name = "name";
modeloBE.age = "age";
modeloBE.phone = "phone";
```

creas los ContentValues

```
ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
initialValues.put("id", modeloBE.id);
initialValues.put("name", modeloBE.name);
initialValues.put("age", modeloBE.age);
initialValues.put("phone", modeloBE.phone);
```

realizas el update a tu tabla

```
   return mDb.update("NOMBRE DE LA TABLA", initialValues, "ACA PONES TU WHERE.", null);
```